# how can i update react child tags state by props data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a react project that is using tags input.

So I have added it successfully. This is working fine with add tag with add product component. But when I'm editing it this is creating problem.

So please tell me how can I update the data of child tags state data? When I'm passing props like `this.state={tags:this.props.data}` then this is throwing error of blank dome.

```js
    //prents component
       <TagsInputEdit  setStateOfTags={this.setStateOfTags} data={this.state.tags}/>
```

```js
    //child component
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import suggestdata from "./tagsData";
    import"./style.css"
    
    class TagsInputEdit extends Component {
         state={
              tags:[],
              input: "",
              suggestions: []
              }
       handleChange = e => {
        const { value } = e.target;
        this.setState({
          input: value
        });
        this.handleSuggestion();
      };
    
      handleKeyDown = e => {
        if (e.keyCode === 9) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
        const { tags, input, suggestions } = this.state;
        const text = suggestions.length ? suggestions[0].text : input;
        if ([9, 13].includes(e.keyCode) && text) {
          this.setState({
            tags: [...tags, text],
            input: ""
          });
        }
      };
    
      handleSuggestion = () => {
        const { input, tags } = this.state;
        const suggestFilterInput = suggestdata.filter(suggest =>
          suggest.text.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())
        );
    
        const suggestFilterTags = suggestFilterInput.filter(
          suggest => !tags.includes(suggest.text)
        );
    
        this.setState({
          suggestions: suggestFilterTags
        });
      };
    
      handleDelete = i => {
        const { tags } = this.state;
        const newTags = tags.filter((tag, j) => i !== j);
        this.setState({
          tags: newTags
        });
      };
    
      AddTags = async  (text) => {
        this.setState({
          tags: [...this.state.tags, text],
          input: ""
        });
        await this.props.setStateOfTags( [...this.state.tags, text])
      };
    
      render() {
        const { tags, input, suggestions } = this.state;
     
          //  this.state.tags.push(this.props.data)
           console.log(tags,"tagdata")
      
            // tags.push(this.props.data.)
        console.log(this.props.data)
        return (
          <div className="tags-content">
            {tags.map((tag, i) => (
              <div key={i} className="tag">
                {tag}
                <div className="remove-tag" onClick={() => this.handleDelete(i)}>
                  ×
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
            <div className="tags-input">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={input}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
                placeholder="add new tag"
              />
              {input && Boolean(suggestions.length) && (
                <div className="tags-suggestions">
                  {suggestions.map(suggest => (
                    <div
                      className="suggestion-item"
                      onClick={() => this.AddTags(suggest.text)}
                    >
                      {suggest.text}
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

[image: here is image of tags and form input please look and suggest me where am i doing wrong??]

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is the issue you are asking about? I've pored over the code and reread the question a few times. Are you just wanting to duplicate the `this.state.tags` state of the parent component in the child component? If so, this is considered anti-pattern in React. Just use the passed `data` prop in the child component.

Comment: im unable to show the tags name which i have to edit

Comment: im not able to edit the tags data.can you guide me where is my error??

Comment: I see. Just FYI, the `this.state.input` won't have updated yet when `handleSuggestion` is called because React state updates are processed asynchronously.

Comment: how could i do it??

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add a minimal demo in a *running* codesandbox that we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try like this **`{this?.props?.data}`** because it would allow you to execute the code without getting an error plus this would return undefined(if the props are not receiving) in which case you would be able to trace it down why is this all happening